# What is the purpose of HTTP Watch Pro?

Tags: http

What is the purpose of this software?

[**http://www.httpwatch.com/**](http://www.httpwatch.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the HTTPFox add-on for FireFox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647

and Fiddler for IE:
http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/

both offer similar functionality to httpwatch (but they are free).

Answer (score 2):

It helps you analyze/debug/monitor the HTTP comunication between server and browser. It runs on the browser and tracks all HTTP traffic.

A small part of this task is also done by the firefox plugin [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/3829)